# How to say to a cashier that I want this stuff to get delivered to my home?

Tags: spoken-english

A supermarket near my home offers the delivery service.
How should I tell the cashier that I want these items to get delivered to my home?

I usually say "It’s for delivery" but it doesn't sound natural.  How should I say that?

Comment: Does the cashier speak English? Maybe you could ask how the other customers request delivery.

Answer (score 1):

If the stuff is being delivered when you say "It's for delivery" then all is well.  Clearly in that case, you are speaking English and it is understood.

I'd just say "I want this stuff to get delivered to my home, please" or some variation on that.  There's no standard phrase or magic word for this.